# proper use of indexOf in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript object:

```
console.log( 'TYPE OF MY OBJECT:' + typeof myObject );
console.log( 'MY OBJECT:' + myObject );
```

Result:

```
TYPE OF MY OBJECT:object
MY OBJECT:der,die,das
```

How can I find if a string is present in this object?

I tried with indexOf but it does not seems to work because the alert box never shows up:

```
var stringToFind = 'der';
if ( Object.keys( myObject ).indexOf( stringToFind ) != -1 ) {
    alert('OK');
}
```

I also tried this:

```
var stringToFind = 'der';
if ( myObject.indexOf( stringToFind ) != -1 ) {
    alert('OK');
}
```

It throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Finally I tried this

```
var stringToFind = 'der';
if ( Object.values( myObject ).indexOf( stringToFind ) != -1 ) {
    alert('OK');
}
```

And it also throws the same error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Can you share what `myObject` looks like? You can get its value by doing `console.log(myObject)` (without concatenating it to any strings)

Comment: Your ``myObject`` looks like an array. Can you please share the ``myObject``

Comment: console.log( 'MY OBJECT:' + myObject ); gives MY OBJECT:der,die,das without concatenating it. @jateen yes you are right, it is an array, so i assume i will have to use "find"

Comment: thank you for the help, it is solved! additionally there was another mistake in my code, once again thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Objects does not have "strings". They have "properties", which can be anything.

If you would like to check if a property exist on an object, you can do the following.

```js
var myObject = {
  foo: 123
}

typeof myObject.foo // "Number"
typeof myObject.bar // "undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf()` is used to get position of a substring over a string or get position of an element in array.

> If it fails to find element then function will return -1

for example.

```js
// With string
const str = "this string contains a substring.";

console.log(str.indexOf( "substring"));     // returns 23
console.log(str.indexOf( "not in str" ));   // returns -1

// With list
const fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape'];
console.log(fruits.indexOf( 'grape' ))      // returns 2
console.log(fruits.indexOf( 'gra'   ))      // returns -1 since 'gra' is not a element of fruits array

// If you want to find 'grape' with 'gra'
const result = fruits.filter((fruit) => { if (fruit.indexOf('gra') !== -1) return fruit});
console.log( result ) // returns ["grape"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an array, you can check the below code for the use case of indexOf method.

```js
const stringToFind = 'die';
const myArray = ['der', 'die', 'das'];

if(myArray.indexOf(stringToFind)) {
  alert("OK");
}
```

Also I would suggest you to please name the variables following the good convention practices, just so to increase the readability of your code.